# Cropping big size image and set in imageview's frame

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, cgrect

This question asked lots of time but my question is quite different.

i am getting image from **Json** (web service). it's like "http:/address/upload/book_icon/4353988696.jpg".

i need to show the images in **85 * 130 size** fit in imageview. but most of the images are having much more size.

for Example : if image is having size 1000*650 then how i set this image in 85*130 and without download it.

for better speed of showing the image i am using "SDWebImageManagerDelegate" but need to crop image in speed and show it in imageview with out download it.

i did so far...

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 85,130)];
        [imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        imgView.tag = i;
```

but didn't Used below line for getting image because of cropping the image...

```
        [imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.png"]];
```

and used this for getting image...

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];
        UIImage *image123temp = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIImage *objimgtemp = [self imageCrop:image123temp];

        imgView.image = objimgtemp;
```

and cropped image using this method

```
-(UIImage*)imageCrop:(UIImage*)original
{
UIImage *ret = nil;

// This calculates the crop area.

float originalWidth  = original.size.width;
float originalHeight = original.size.height;

float edge = fminf(originalWidth, originalHeight);

float posX = (originalWidth   - edge) / 2.0f;
float posY = (originalHeight  - edge) / 2.0f;


CGRect cropSquare = CGRectMake(posX, posY,
                               edge, edge);


// This performs the image cropping.

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([original CGImage], cropSquare);

ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef
                          scale:original.scale
                    orientation:original.imageOrientation];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);

NSLog(@"ret.......... %f == %f",ret.size.width,ret.size.height);

return ret;
}
```

How to get cropped image fast ?

Any link, tutorial, suggestion, code, will be great help...

Comment: You mean like get a thumbnail from the server? This is what it is generally done but the server must support the thumbnails. I see no other way how you would do that on your own. If all you can get is a whole image file you need to download a whole file, decompress it on the memory and only after that you can crop, present or do anything with it...

Answer (score 0):

The image located at the remote URL is always downloaded as is. Anything that creates a thumbnail version of the image at the remote server or autoscales/autocrops the image when the client requests it
is a server-side process not a client-side one.

Now what you could do is create a simple server-side webrequest (in PHP or some other language) which returns a
cropped image that would of course be smaller in size.
Then you would do somehting like this on the client side:

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/getCroppedImage?width=%f&height=%f&imagename=%@", width, height, someImageName];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];
```